# How to transform the Object into FeatureCollection on GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, feature-collection

I tried to use GEE to export the `Featurecollection`  at **script1**, and use `require()` to call the exported `Featurecollection`  from **script1** to **script2**. The reason I'm doing this is to separate the data processing into different scripts so it may ease the burden of calculation and the memory. However, the property I exported is  `Featurecollection`  at **script1**, and when I require it at **script2**, it turns out to be an `Object`, so I cannot continue the further script because of the *error: Line 5: s1s2_sample.randomColumn is not a function.*

Does anyone know how to convert the `Object` to `Featurecollection` ? This is the code of **script1**

```
var S1_2021_VV = s1L2021predb.select('VV');
var S1_2021_VH = s1L2021predb.select('VH');

var S1S2_2021 = s2L2021c_Veg.addBands(S1_2021_VV).addBands(S1_2021_VH);
//print(S1S2_2021);

//MASK THE WATER
// Select the land/water mask.
var datamask = S1S2_2021.select('AWEInsh');
//Map.addLayer(datamask);

// Create a binary mask.
var mask = datamask.lte(-9000);

// Update the composite mask with the water mask.
var S1S2_2021m = S1S2_2021.updateMask(mask);
//Map.addLayer(S1S2_2021m, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min: 0, max: 3000}, 'S1S2_2018m');

var s1s2_sample = S1S2_2021m.sampleRegions({
  collection: trainingData,
  scale: 10,
  properties: ['AGB_DW'],
  projection: 'EPSG:3006',
  tileScale: 16 
});

//print(s1s2_sample)
exports.s1s2_sample = s1s2_sample
```

and the code below is **script2**

````
var s1s2_sample = require('users/sentinel2_import_resample/fail20230410:2021sweden_1preprocess');
print(s1s2_sample)

//model trained by 80% of the data, and 20% for validation
var random = s1s2_sample.randomColumn()
var validation = random.filter(ee.Filter.lt('random',0.2)) //<
var training = random.filter(ee.Filter.gte('random',0.2))  //>=


var variables2021 = ['VV','VH','B1','B2','B3','B4','B5','B6','B7','B8','B8A','B9','B11','B12','NDVI','RVI','EVI','NDVIn','NDVIre','DVI','Vigreen','GNDVI','SAVI','MSAVI','ARVI','NDI45'];

var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(10).train({
  features: training,
  classProperty: 'AGB_DW',
  inputProperties: variables2021
}).setOutputMode('REGRESSION');

var classified2021 = S1S2_2021m.select(variables2021).classify(classifier).toInt();

exports.classified2021 = classified2021```
````

Answer (score 0):

The feature collection that you want (`s1s2_sample` in script1) is within the object that you defined as `s1s2_sample` in script2. I suggest that you retrieve it as:

```js
var preprocess = require('users/sentinel2_import_resample/fail20230410:2021sweden_1preprocess');
var s1s2_sample = preprocess.s1s2_sample;
```

Here's a more detailed explanation of how to work with the `exports` object in script1 and what happens when you do `require` in script2:

```js
// Script 1:
var fc = ee.FeatureCollection([
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(-120,39).buffer(10000),{"foo":"bar"})
  ])
exports.fc = fc; // Adding the feature collection to the "exports" object.
exports.other = "stuff" // The "exports" object might contain other stuff.

// To simulate what this does without having to write two scripts, let's 
// define another object called "exp":
var exp = {};   
exp.fc = fc    
exp.other = "stuff"

// Script 2:
// When you do require("script1");
// in another script, it returns an object containing everything that you 
// put into the "exports" object in script1
// To simulate this here, we can do:
var loaded_module = exp  // This is an Object. 
print("Loaded module: ", loaded_module) // It should contain both "fc" and "other" 

// To get the feature collection, simply use dot notation:
var loaded_fc = loaded_module.fc  
print("Loaded feature collection:", loaded_fc)
```